# Django Add multiple dropdown and select value in admin panel

Tags: django

In my extended User model I am trying to add dropdown like feature in admin panel and I understood that if I create ForeignKey relationship then in admin panel I can see the dropdown. But right now I want multiple dropdown, like on click we can select multiple values.

I tried creating ManyToMany field but then the widget forces you to select but I am interested in having Select type of feature.

I have my UserProfile as:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_year = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyYear)
    company_name = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyName)
```

CompanyName has just 1 field of CharType and CompanyYear has 1 field in IntegerType. In admin panel I am trying to do it like:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile


class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

So right now things are working fine but I just want to have this dropdown like feature but I am not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `blank=True` on the field:

```
company_name = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyName, blank=True)
```

Note that it won't be a dropdown widget, but instead a multi-select widget.